# How to remove characters from an item in an array using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have an array of computer names, $computers, that are in a FQDN format.  I want to trim all characters to the right of the first period and including the period.

Ex: server-01.mydomain.int = server-01

This is what I tried but it errors out.

```
$computers = Get-VM | Select Name
$computers = $computers.Substring(0, $computers.IndexOf('.'))
$computers
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do `|Select Name`, PowerShell returns an object with a `Name` property, rather than only the value of each `Name` property of the input objects.

You could change it to `Select -ExpandProperty Name` and then iterate over each item in the array for the actual substring operation using a loop or `ForEach-Object` - although we can skip the first step completely:

```
$computers = Get-VM |ForEach-Object { $_.Name.Substring(0, $_.Name.Indexof('.')) }
```

Comment: @Steve Forgot the `Name` property in the second function call, updated now

Comment: Thank you very much!  The output is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Or another way.

```
$computers = Get-VM | ForEach-Object { ($_.Name -split ".")[0] }
```

Since you are always selecting the first string before the first "." you can just split at the dot and select the first element in the resulting array.